# Is there any way to respec?

Tags: torchlight-2

I have just loaded up Torchlight 2 and started to look at the skill tree for my character. The very first thought I had was, "Oh crap, there are 3 trees. I wonder if I pick one I don't like, would I be able to change my mind later?"

So, is there any way to respec in Torchlight 2?

Comment: Don't forget Torchlight 2 is moddable, so I'm sure sooner or later you will find a mod the allows respecs at no penalty :)

Comment: Just save all your skill points until the very end, then refer to a guide to perform your desired build properly.  That way you'll feel "invested" in your decisions. :p

Comment: @bwarner That's terrible advice lol.  Good luck surviving to the very end without any skills.

Comment: @jw013 I think that was the joke.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is a way to respec, up to a point.

You have the option to respec **your 3 most recently spent skill points**. This means that you can invest a little into a combo of skills that you want to try, and if you do not like it you can claim up to three points back.

To get a respec visit the NPC in Estherian Enclave, the first town you will find, who will perform skill respecs for you at a small gold price.

You cannot respec your Strength, Dexterity, Focus, and Vitality attributes.

---

**However**, as pointed out in [@ShameFulmer's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/85872/1721), if you don't like the built-in system, you can modify your save file instead. The easiest way is to replace your shared stash save file with one that is full of respec potions. There is such a file available on the forums as [Shared Stash Respec Potions](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=35925).

This *does not* mark you as a cheater.

To summarize the instructions on the forum, being careful to not delete everything currently in your shared stash (it wouldn't hurt to move everything valuable out of there):

1. Ensure that the game is closed and that Steam Cloud saves are disabled.
2. Backup your shared stash save located in `C:\Users\< username >\Documents\My Games\Runic Games\Torchlight 2\save\RandomNumber` (replace < username > with your username). It should be called `sharedstash.bin`. You can either move it somewhere else or change its name.
3. Download the file from the forums and save it to the same location. This will replace your shared stash with respec potions.
4. Open up the game, load the character you want to respec in a single-player game and take as many potions from your shared stash into your character inventory as you want.
5. Close the game and restore the downloaded `sharedstash.bin` with the file that you backed up.
6. Re-enable Steam Cloud saves, and enjoy the game! You will still have your old shared stash and your character should be carrying all of the potions that you took out. You are free to put them back into your shared stash and use them with other characters as well. Using these potions *will not* mark your character as a cheater, like some other methods do.

Comment: Additionally, if you don't mind using the console you could use the `RESETSKILLS` command to reset all skills, at any given time. I can't stand the limited respec so i've used this quite a bit to experiment. (note: if you do use this, it *may* flag you in multiplayer!)

Comment: You can also use the console to spawn respec potions, which will get you flagged as a cheater. OTOH, I'm reading reports of people who are using alts to spawn the potions and then just transferring them over.  Being flagged as a cheater is only cosmetic (though I suppose it's also about pride, heh).

Comment: Well, the game has many mods, and I'm sure there's more than one way to do it. I figure @StrixVaria was only interested in the way the game was primarily designed to have respecs done.

Comment: @Aerus Will using the console block your achievements?

Answer (score 4):

There's also this option from the forums: http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=35925

It is a mod that fills your shared character stash with respec potions in a way that doesn't flag you as a cheater. Be sure to back up your shared stash before using it!

Comment: Can you sum it up by quoting the relevant bits here? We generally dislike link only answers.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to the other answers, you can use the [Torchlight 2 Rapid Respec](http://clockworkcore.org/tl2rr.html) character editor. As it's name suggests it's very fast/easy to respec to a new build. You can also save different builds to swap between, it automatically creates backup files and has [good documentation](http://clockworkcore.org/tl2rrhelp.html).